# What is it called when an app set some configurations at build time?

Tags: vb.net, build, environment-variables, config, app-config

A common pattern used to build applications/software (web, mobile, desktop) is to have multiple build configs like Dev, Stage and Production. Each one of these configs may overwrite multiple variables like the base url of a web service that is consumed by the application. These configs may be stored in multiple ways (.env file, a JSON config file, etc).

I was looking for a name for this pattern/practice and how to implement it on a VB.NET application. Most close thing I was able to found is using the app.config file to store app settings but this is missing the multiple environments part. I'm having some trouble looking for solutions since I don't know the proper term for this practice.

Answer (score 2):

There's a *Solution Configurations* drop-down on the main toolbar. You would have already used it to select *Debug* or *Release*. You can open the *Configuration Manager* from there to create new build configurations.

[image]

You can then control what happens during the build process of a project for a particular configuration on the *Build* page of the project properties. You can also perform actions using build events, which you configure on the *Build Events* page of the project properties. Here's an example of a pre-build event commandline that I use to automatically select the appropriate config file for NLog:

```
IF EXIST "$(ProjectDir)nlog.$(ConfigurationName).config" XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)nlog.$(ConfigurationName).config" "$(ProjectDir)nlog.config" /Y
```

Comment: This is valuable information, however, it doesn't answer the initial answer on what is this practice called. If you get some info around that, I think I could mark this as solved.